# Change the Theme of Account Picker

Tags: android

Is it possible to change theme of account Picker? Now I am getting darkDialog box. Is it possible to change theme to light?

Here is the piece of code: using google play services.

```
Intent googlePicker = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                    new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, true, null, null, null, null);
            startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
```

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047940/android-accountpicker-set-light-theme. Check my answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change style of Google Play Services AccountPicker dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237798/change-style-of-google-play-services-accountpicker-dialog)